# open filesystem window on click in jquery + air

Tags: jquery, filesystems, air, click

Hi to all stackoverflowers.

I've build a HTML5/jQuery application and I've incorporeted it in Adobe AIR.

I'm wondering if and how is it possible to tell AIR to open a filesystem folder window after clicking on a link in the HTML/jQuery application, something like

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   var path = "my/path/"
   openFolder(path);
});
```

I hope I was clear.

Any suggest will be strongly apreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include AIRAliases.js from the air SDK

`<script src="AIRAliases.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and then use the following functions.

```
   function openFolder(path) {
        var file, loader, urlReq;
        file = air.file.resolvePath(path);
        file.addEventListener(air.Event.SELECT, function (e) {
            loader = new air.Loader();
            urlReq = new air.URLRequest(file.url);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoad);
            loader.load(urlReq);
        });
        file.browseForOpen("Open");
    }

    function onFileLoad(e) {
        //Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

//air

```
yourHTMLLoader.window.openFolder= openFolder;     //assign Js function to air function

function openFolder(path:String):void
{
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory;
var fileOpen:File = file.resolvePath(path);
fileOpen.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected); //if you want manage open file
fileOpen.browse(); 
}
```